# "Distribution not supported" when trying to install Intel Graphics Installer in Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel, 14.10

My Ubuntu version is new, and Intel Graphics Installer doesn't allow me to install the Intel video drivers. It says `"Distribution not supported"`
How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That software checks `/etc/lsb-release` and that is a text file we can edit ourself so it might be fairly easy to circumvent. Make a backup first though if you do not know what this means. From a command line:

```
sudo cp /etc/lsb-release /etc/lsb-release.backup
```

And then edit the file ...

```
sudo gedit /etc/lsb-release
```

And change the lines as below:

```
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=utopic
```

And save it. Start the installation and it should finish this time without a notice regarding the distribution.

After that you can then put back the backup file with (`cp` to leave the backup, change it to `mv` to also remove the backup)...

```
sudo cp /etc/lsb-release.backup /etc/lsb-release
```

Comment: This is a bad advice. It will break the system in many cases. It may break dependencies, etc.

Comment: no it is not and does not @Pilot6 Mind the "After that you can then put back the backup file with" makes it --harmless-- and it only circumvents the stupid check from the installer.

Comment: That backup does not fix anything. It is very hard to revert that driver install to normal Ubuntu packages, if something goes wrong.

Comment: If something goes wrong it is not due to this temporary alteration. Have you even tried it with a none working installation? I have and I can tell you it worked flawlessly. There is no check when removing and all is removed as it should. Very simple if you get this notice:  you either can *not* install Ubuntu or you use this and can install it. Simple choice for me. Feel free to provide an answer yourself for this.

Comment: I get this error "W:Failed to fetch http://... Hash Sum mismatch ... Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead."

Comment: @MuhammadAhmadZafar means an incorrect download/source file.

Comment: This solution does not work. (Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: This ONLY works for a buggy version check. Not if the actual video card is NOT supported @MathManiac

Comment: Worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04.1 BUT by changing version in lsb_release from 16.04 LTS to 15.04 LTS. The installer seems to check for LTS...