# Distribution not supported error when trying to install Intel Graphics Installer on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, intel-graphics, intel, lts

My processor is **Intel core i3 inside x64 bit** and **RAM is 4 gb**. When I used Windows 7 Intel was successfully installing, but now I am using **Ubuntu 14.04** and Intel Installer makes me crazy!!! I've tried to change lsb-release, but is doesn't help me. I tried to reinstall signature and Intel Installer, but everything is the same!

I heard [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553581/distribution-not-supported-when-trying-to-install-intel-graphics-installer-in) was on **Ubuntu 14.10**, but not on **Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS**. If someone knows why I have this error please help me...

[image]

Comment: download the old 14.04 version here https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main/pool/main/i/intel-linux-graphics-installer/intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.7-0intel1_amd64.deb

Comment: the only thing I had to do to find the file was change 14.10 to 14.04 and 1.0.8 to 1.0.7 in the download url and voila

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most versions of the Linux operating system include Intel graphics drivers.  Intel recommends checking with your Linux distribution vendor or computer manufacturer for precompiled driver packages.<sup>[Intel](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/13815/Intel-Graphics-Drivers-for-Linux-)</sup>

The Intel Graphics Installer for Linux allows you to easily install the latest graphics and video drivers for your Intel graphics hardware. This allows you to stay current with the latest enhancements, optimizations, and fixes to the Intel® Graphics Stack to ensure the best user experience with your Intel graphics hardware. The Intel Graphics Installer for Linux is available for the latest versions of Ubuntu.

NOTE (updated 18 March 2015 09:15 UTC-7): This release of the Graphics Installer requires Ubuntu 14.10 "utopic". **The Graphics Installer will not function on Ubuntu 14.04 "trusty"** and support is deprecated (see this forum announcement and this explanation).<sup>[The Intel Graphics Installer for Linux](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2015/intelr-graphics-installer-linux-1.0.8)</sup>

You can try using the older driver, but I have no way of verifying that it will work.  Depending on your needs, download the [32bit](https://copy.com/TLS9i1XxeHrguPut) or [64bit](https://copy.com/Hpp9rUt8FeidVZbF) or you can download the file from source: for [32bit](https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main/pool/main/i/intel-linux-graphics-installer/intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.7-0intel1_i386.deb) or [64bit](https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main/pool/main/i/intel-linux-graphics-installer/intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.7-0intel1_amd64.deb) and then follow the commands below:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg -O - | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
For 32 bit:
sudo dpkg -i intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.7-0intel1_i386.deb
OR for 64 bit:
sudo dpkg -i intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.7-0intel1_amd64.deb
```

And then just start the installer

```
sudo intel-linux-graphics-installer
```

I would recommend you install the file(s) using Gdebi.  To install:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Comment: can i change my lsb-release and instead of 14.04 write 14.10, instead of trusty write utopic?

Comment: You really don't have to install anything. just do `lshw -c video` to see driver loaded.  also take a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/23238/how-can-i-find-what-video-driver-is-in-use-on-my-system).

Comment: If the answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://$SITEURL$/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Comment: Without installing anything, I have the [missing letters problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/584922/how-do-i-fix-fonts-not-rendering-and-missing-letters), like many others.

Comment: See added info in my answer.

Comment: Installing the 1.0.7 installer does nothing & the installer itself, when run, will do nothing on 14.04.x. So just a waste of time..

Comment: @doug How did you test the driver?

Comment: By installing the Intel installer, then running it. It will exit on error of distribution not supported. To note - prior to Intel pulling support for 14.04 I did use it to see, really nothing better than what's already supplied or available from elsewhere (like libva, i965-va-driver 1.5.x from various ppa's, ect.

Comment: The answer worked for the OP, so I guess I don't understand why it doesn't work for others, and the downvotes :)

Comment: @doug if you are using 14.04 and you install VERSION 1.0.7 and you also have the utopic -lts 3.16 kernel for 14.04 installed, it should add an extra i915-3.18-3.16-dkms driver. This will even work for on debian jessie adding the proper missing lsb file and using an ubuntu kernel.

Comment: I got `gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.` when I run `wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg -O - | sudo apt-key add -`, What should I do? Also when I install 1.0.7 version still got same error (Distribution not supported). Please help me!

Comment: @Daniyal Which Ubuntu version are you running?

Comment: 14.04.2 .Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @Daniyal Try running this `"gpg --import KEYS" "sudo apt-get update"`

Comment: When I run `gpg --import KEYS` got the `gpg: can't open \`KEYS': No such file or directory
gpg: Total number processed: 0` error

Comment: Is it possible that graphic installer no longer support 14.04.2? https://01.org/linuxgraphics/node/471

Comment: Yes that is possible.   I think that Intel finally removed the driver.

Answer (score 3):

Because the installer could not work with 14.04.2 (HWE) or if a 14.04.1 user of the installer tried to install the lts-utopic mesa stack they've dropped any further support for 14.04.x

Read here for announcement - https://01.org/linuxgraphics/node/471

Personally don't think the Intel installer provided anything of real value, at least here with Haswell (mobile)

Updates for libva & vaapi are available from several ppa's, search if interested there.

Comment: is there other methods to install intel graphicks or i must to upgrade to 14.10?

Comment: @tony just download the older version for 14.04 directly from the repository https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main/pool/main/i/intel-linux-graphics-installer/intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.7-0intel1_amd64.deb

Comment: I install 1.07 version but still got same error, any idea?

Comment: " install 1.07 version but still got same error, any idea? –  Daniyal" The installer is, as mentioned, worthless in 14.04. So best 'idea' is  - accept that FACT.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I managed to install Intel Linux graphics driver:

For Ubuntu 14.04 with kernel **linux-image-3.16.0-30**:

1. Install kernel If not yet installed:

   ```
   sudo apt-get linux-image-3.16.0-30-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-30-generic linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic
   ```
2. Remove old kernels, e.g.:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-24 linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic
   ```
3. Add Intel Linux graphics repo:

   ```
   sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main trusty main #intel-linux-graphics-installer" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/intellinuxgraphics.list'  
   wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg -O - | sudo apt-key add -
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Install driver:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall i915-3.16-3.13-dkms xserver-xorg-video-intel i965-va-driver intel-gpu-tools
   ```

   Next step might be unnecessary if backlight change works for you:
5. Add kernel param: `acpi_osi=Linux` instead of: `acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor` to linux line in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` via [grub-customizer](https://launchpad.net/%7Edanielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer).

   Next step might be unnecessary if backlight change works for you:
6. Create file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` with content:

   ```
   Section "Device"
           Identifier "card0"
           Driver "Intel"
           Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight"
           BusID "PCI:0:2:0"
   EndSection
   ```
7. Update initramfs:

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
   ```

And it works after reboot.

Comment: I have linux kernal 4.4.0-109-generic on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Will you solution work?

Comment: Yes, if you agree to downgrade to kernel 3.16.0-30-generic and uninstall you current one as described in step **2.**