# Enemy Territory on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Dell Latitude E6440 Laptop)

Tags: 14.04, drivers, dell, games, intel-graphics

I am trying to setup [Wolfenstein: Enemy Territory](http://www.splashdamage.com/content/wolfenstein-enemy-territory-barracks) in my [laptop (Dell E6440)](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/servicetag/JM13H12/drivers). :P 
I can run the game but getting bad graphics (black) like this.

[image]

**Following are my laptop specs.**

[image]

[image]

```
amilai@amilai-Latitude-E6440:~$ sudo lshw -C display
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:48 memory:f5800000-f5bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

And I installed the Intel Graphics Installer ( **intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.7-0intel1_amd64.deb** )
https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main/pool/main/i/intel-linux-graphics-installer/. But I get this error.

[image]
[image]

```
amilai@amilai-Latitude-E6440:~$ sudo intel-linux-graphics-installer 

(intel-linux-graphics-installer:5650): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
diagnostics-view.c/new_diagnostic: Adding diagnostic for Checking if Intel graphics card available...
diagnostics-view.c/new_diagnostic: Adding diagnostic for Retrieving information from 01.org...
diagnostics-view.c/new_diagnostic: Adding diagnostic for Checking distribution...
diagnostics-view.c/new_diagnostic: Adding diagnostic for Checking kernel version...
diagnostics-view.c/new_diagnostic: Adding diagnostic for Checking available repositories...
diagnostics-view.c/new_diagnostic: Adding diagnostic for Checking package manager status...
No LSB modules are available.
polkit: Fetching org.01.linuxgraphics.installer permissions...
diagnostics-view.c/diagnostics_view_start: Running diagnostic Checking if Intel graphics card available...
diagnostics-view.c/diagnostics_view_start: Running diagnostic Retrieving information from 01.org...
{
  errors: (nil)
  sources: []
  keys: []
  docs: []
  INSTALL: []
  install: []
  upgrade: []
}
diagnostics-view.c/diagnostics_view_start: Running diagnostic Checking distribution...
 package_manager_is_distro_supported
 Configuration : Loading …  [   0 % ] ⏲
{
  errors: (nil)
  sources: []
  keys: []
  docs: []
  INSTALL: []
  install: []
  upgrade: []
}
 package_manager_is_distro_supported
 Configuration : Loaded  [  80 % ] ⏲
 package_manager_is_distro_supported
 Configuration : Testing …  [  80 % ] ⏲
 package_manager_is_distro_supported
 Configuration : Complete  [  ] ◦
```

Distribution Not supported. So I found some solutions , but didn't work for me
[Distribution not supported error when trying to install Intel Graphics Installer on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601088/distribution-not-supported-error-when-trying-to-install-intel-graphics-installer)

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg -O - | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
For 32 bit:
sudo dpkg -i intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.7-0intel1_i386.deb
OR for 64 bit:
sudo dpkg -i intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.7-0intel1_amd64.deb
```

I setup the game from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnemyTerritory
And installed these dependencies also.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libdrm2:i386 libexpat1:i386 libgcc1:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libx11-6:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxshmfence1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 libasound2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386
```

This is my game file hierarchy in case.
[image]

Please help me out to solve this graphic problem .... :) :)
Thanks

Comment: what error you get from installing linux graphics installer ?

Comment: Distribution not supported.. As I mentioned above.. IS that what ur asking or ?

Comment: Do you get error on terminal after run installing command ?

Comment: I posted the terminal output when running the intel linux installer

Comment: Please post the output instead of post screenshot

Comment: done .. seems like pictures i have posted is not showing :(