# Distribution not supported error when trying to install Intel Graphics Installer on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: intel-graphics

How do I install the Intel Graphics Installer 1.08 32-bit on Ubuntu 15.04? I'm getting "Distribution not supported error".

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/601088/distribution-not-supported-error-when-trying-to-install-intel-graphics-installer and http://askubuntu.com/questions/553581/distribution-not-supported-when-trying-to-install-intel-graphics-installer-in (2nd one; my answer works but is a hack) I do agree with Pilot6 though: if you do not need it do not install it. My hack was needed to even install Ubuntu. If you have a working system don't use it if the installer says it is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I do not recommend to install this package, if you do not have a serious reason for that. Intel drivers that are already installed in Ubuntu are good. It will be hard to remove that package and it may conflict with future updates.

This package is not intended for Ubuntu 15.04. Future release may support it, but as I wrote earlier it is not too good to install it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [01.org](http://01.org), the next release of the Intel Graphics installer q2-2015 is supposed to be made available for 15.04. There is no know release date for that as of yet though. I have asked on the forum for an update.