# Characters missing / corrupted text Ubuntu 14.04 (and other versions) Intel 5th gen

Tags: 14.04, intel, text

In Ubuntu 14.04 from one day to another characters start to be missing in all applications (Ubuntu menus, thunderbird, etc).

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

As already stated characters are missing all over the place. The reason seems to be an outdated Intel Graphics driver in Ubuntu 14.04 - which is not compatible with the 5th generation of Intel CPU/GPU. As noticed and further described in [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1342675)

["Distribution not supported" when trying to install Intel Graphics Installer in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553581/distribution-not-supported-when-trying-to-install-intel-graphics-installer-in) describes how the *Intel Graphics Installer for Linux* starts. But unfortunately it does not succeed. The reason is that Ubuntu 14.04 is not supported. Ubuntu 14.10 is required.

**Edit 04.12.2017**
This problem does not exist using Ubuntu 16.04
Therefore I recommend: **upgrade to 16.04**

Comment: Wow this is an old post - with 16.04 this should be no problem any more. I'll update to use 16.04 now. 16.04 was not available at that time

Comment: I removed the dangerous part

Comment: But what about if the user can not upgrade to ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Using repositories from a higher version will just break the packaging system. Anyway, nobody can use 14.10 safely, because it is no longer supported